# Como aplicar StyledEditorKit a um JTextPane sem precisar herdar esta classe na minha tela?

Tags: java, swing

Tenho um problema com tabulação no `JTextPane` e estou tentando reduzir o valor default atribuído a ele mas tá dando um erro  pois tenho que herdar duas classes(uma para o `JFrame` e a outra para poder sobrescrever as funções de tabulação) mas Java aparentemente, do modo que estou tentando não aceita isso, segue o código:

```
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.BoxView;
import javax.swing.text.ComponentView;
import javax.swing.text.IconView;
import javax.swing.text.LabelView;
import javax.swing.text.ParagraphView;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import static javax.swing.text.StyleConstants.TabSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.TabSet;
import javax.swing.text.View;
import javax.swing.text.ViewFactory;



public class TAB extends javax.swing.JFrame,StyledEditorKit  {
public static final int TAB_SIZE=36;
    /**
     * Creates new form TAB
     */
    public TAB() {
        initComponents();

    }
     @Override
    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        return new MyViewFactory();
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextPane1 = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextPane1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 195, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */





    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TAB.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TAB.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TAB.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TAB.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                new TAB().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        class MyViewFactory implements ViewFactory {

        @Override
        public View create(javax.swing.text.Element elem) {
            String kind = elem.getName();
            if (kind != null) {
                if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName)) {
                    return new LabelView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName)) {
                    return new CustomTabParagraphView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.SectionElementName)) {
                    return new BoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);
                } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.ComponentElementName)) {
                    return new ComponentView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.IconElementName)) {
                    return new IconView(elem);
                }
            }

            return new LabelView(elem);
        }
    }


    class CustomTabParagraphView extends ParagraphView {

        public CustomTabParagraphView(javax.swing.text.Element elem) {
            super(elem);
        }

        @Override
        public float nextTabStop(float x, int tabOffset) {
            TabSet tabs = getTabSet();
            if(tabs == null) {
                // a tab every 72 pixels.
                return (float)(getTabBase() + (((int)x / TAB_SIZE + 1) * TAB_SIZE));
            }

            return super.nextTabStop(x, tabOffset);
        }

    }

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Não existe herança multipla em java. Use composição para uma das duas classes herdadas(neste caso, recomendo fazer isso para o JFrame)

Comment: Possível duplicada de [Java não possui herança múltipla?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22718/44744)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No caso do seu código, basta separar a classe `TabSizeEditorKit` da sua classe de tela e instanciar dentro do método [**`setEditorKit()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setEditorKit-javax.swing.text.EditorKit-), conforme está no exemplo da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/160158/28595).

Ficaria algo assim:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;

    public class Tela extends JFrame {

        private JPanel contentPane;
        private JEditorPane editorPane;


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Tela frame = new Tela();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Create the frame.
         * @throws BadLocationException 
         */
        public Tela() throws BadLocationException {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 332, 300);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);

            editorPane = new JEditorPane();
            GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
            gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
                gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(31)
                        .addComponent(editorPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 251, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(142, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
                gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(37)
                        .addComponent(editorPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 186, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(29, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
            //aqui que você seta o editorkit customizado
            //para o editorpane
            editorPane.setEditorKit(new TabSizeEditorKit());
        }
    }
```

e a classe `TabSizeEditorKit` você remove o `main` e deixa apenas o essencial para ela funcionar:

```
import javax.swing.text.*;


public class TabSizeEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit {

    public static final int TAB_SIZE=36;

    @Override
    public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
        return new MyViewFactory();
    }

    static class MyViewFactory implements ViewFactory {

        @Override
        public View create(Element elem) {
            String kind = elem.getName();
            if (kind != null) {
                if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName)) {
                    return new LabelView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName)) {
                    return new CustomTabParagraphView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(AbstractDocument.SectionElementName)) {
                    return new BoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);
                } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.ComponentElementName)) {
                    return new ComponentView(elem);
                } else if (kind.equals(StyleConstants.IconElementName)) {
                    return new IconView(elem);
                }
            }

            return new LabelView(elem);
        }
    }


    static class CustomTabParagraphView extends ParagraphView {

        public CustomTabParagraphView(Element elem) {
            super(elem);
        }

        @Override
        public float nextTabStop(float x, int tabOffset) {
            TabSet tabs = getTabSet();
            if(tabs == null) {
                // a tab every 72 pixels.
                return (float)(getTabBase() + (((int)x / TAB_SIZE + 1) * TAB_SIZE));
            }

            return super.nextTabStop(x, tabOffset);
        }

    }
}
```

Como você só irá fazer uso da `TabSizeEditorKit` apenas pela questão do espaçamento, não é preciso transformar ela em um atributo da classe.

Comment: estamos quase lá. já ajustei o espaçamento para o tamanho que eu queria mas  ele ainda fica mostrando aqueles valores ao iniciar. Tem como ele não mostrar isso pra eu não ter que ficar sobrescrevendo o jTextPane a cada vez que iniciar ?

Comment: Pronto, agora deu certo. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 6):

**O java não possui herança múltipla por design.** Os criadores do Java decidiram que prover herança múltipla adicionaria muita complexidade e poucos benefícios a linguagem.

Por exemplo, o que fazer quando duas classes definem o mesmo método e uma terceira classe tentasse estender as duas primeiras?

```
public class Humano {
    public void Andar() {
        // Andar feito Humano
    }
}

public class Robo {
    public void Andar() {
        // Andar feito Robo
    }
}

public class Ciborgue extends Humano, Robo {
    // O ciborgue andaria como robo ou humano? 
}
```

**Considere usar composição.** Escolha uma classe para `TAB` estender e mantenha uma referencia de uma instância da outra classe. Exemplo:

```
// imports...

public class TAB extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private StyledEditorKit editorKit;

    public TAB(){
        editorKit = new StyledEditorKit();
    }

    public void FazerAlgoComEditorKit(){
        // Use a propriedade editorKit
    }
}
```

Comment: Só um detalhe, a classe `StyledEditorKit` não é parte de um JFrame, e sim, de um componente específico que será parte do JFrame, no caso, `JEditorPane`. Creio que transformar em um atributo não seja necessário.